Section not hidden before css/javascript transition
I'm quite new to css/javascript/shopify liquid but I'm trying to bug fix a section of text that animates in when you scroll. At the moment as you scroll slowly the section can be seen before scrolling further when it will disappear and then the transition will happen correctly.
Below is my js code:
$(document).ready(function() {
  var reapplyAnimation = function(element, animationClass) {
    // Remove the class to reset the animation
    $(element).removeClass(animationClass);
    setTimeout(function() {
      // Re-add the class to trigger the animation
      $(element).addClass(animationClass);
    }, 50); // A slight delay ensures the class change is recognized
  };

  $('.blob').each(function() {
    var blobElement = this;
    new Waypoint({
      element: blobElement,
      handler: function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
          // Apply animations to the blob and image as before
          reapplyAnimation(blobElement, 'animated-fade-rotate');
          var relatedImage = $(blobElement).closest('.custom-image-text-section').find('.image-container img')[0];
          reapplyAnimation(relatedImage, 'animated-slide-rotate');

          // Now also target the text container for its animation
          var textContainer = $(blobElement).closest('.custom-image-text-section').find('#text-container')[0];
          reapplyAnimation(textContainer, 'animated-fade-in-slide-in-right');
        }
      },
      offset: '75%' // Trigger point
    });
  });
});

I'm able to set the opacity of the section to 0 in the css but I need a way for this script to then override that opacity and transition it to 1 over the course of the animation. Below is the keyframes animation that as far as I can see should be able to change the opacity but it doesn't.
@keyframes fadeInSlideInRight {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50%); /* Start from the right */
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0); /* Slide to its original position */
    }
}

.animated-fade-in-slide-in-right {
  animation: fadeInSlideInRight 800ms ease-out forwards;
}

Please forgive me if I haven't answered the question very well ,I'm only just getting used to the languages!

The keyframes does change the opacity from 0 to 1. It's just that 800ms and ease-out are not long enough for you to see it. Try changing the speed to 3000ms and you will see.
You can however set multiple animations with different timing effects such as ease-in on the same element.
Based on your current design, one way could be like so:
@keyframes slideInRight {
    from {
        transform: translateX(50%); /* Start from the right */
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0); /* Slide to its original position */
    }
}
@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.animated-fade-in-slide-in-right {
    animation: slideInRight 800ms ease-out forwards, fadeInOpacity 800ms ease-in;
}


Thank you, I'm thinking there's a duplication somewhere in the code as it sounds as if what I posted should be working. If I scroll slowly I can see the section (or part of it) until it reaches the trigger point and fades in correctly. I want it to be hidden on scroll until the trigger point.

I've managed to break the code but in reverse, now it fades in but diseappears when the animation is complete, the fix for that should be the same but backwards for the other part.

If you share the html it might be a bit more clear what your intention is. Keyframes can allow you to set percentage values so you could have the opacity set to 0 right up until 75% of the animation for example.

The website in question is thewaterprofessor.com. If you scroll down you'll see four sections that transition in, it was our first go at anything like this. I've already fixed it so the animation doesn't happen every time you scroll it's just not in the live env at the moment, my plan is also to slow the animation. But you can see that the text can be seen before the animation is triggered if you scroll slowly.

Yes I can see the issue now. I wouldn't use keyframes for this. I would simply have your element as transform: translateX(50%); opacity: 0;   transition: all ease-in 800ms; as default then based on your scroll add a new class with transform: translateX(0%); opacity: 1; You need to have opacity: 0 and translate(50%) when the page loads.

Ok I can have a go at that, so how would I apply that when the different elements move in different ways? Eg my text slides and fades. One blob fades and spins and the other spins and slides. I plan to tweak the movements I realise it looks like a powerpoint at the moment :)

If you have multiple animations then using keyframes is OK but because you have opacity: 0 at the 0% start of the animation you need to ensure you have opacity: 0 set on the element of first load. However, you are going to be chasing your tail because when the keyframe finishes on  opacity: 1 it will revert back to opacity: 0 as soon as the animation completes. That's why simply using a transition would work better. If you really want to use keyframes just have a hidden class of opacity: 0 on first load that you remove as soon as you add the keyframe class.

I'm with you now, that makes sense. I've now got it all hidden on load, but I see it appear for a split second when I remove the hidden-on-load class before it applies the animation.

Is that because of your 50ms timing delay perhaps?

That's what I thought, I think it's having an effect. I've set both to 0 and I'm still seeing a flash, almost like it can't do it instantaneously? I'll keep trying.

Seems like the setTimeout has a minimum of around 4ms, makes me think the code will have to be rethought to have no delay.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var reapplyAnimation = function(element, animationClass) {

    void element.offsetWidth;

    $(element).addClass(animationClass);
  };

  $('.blob').each(function() {
    var blobElement = this;
    var animated = false;
    var section = $(blobElement).closest('.custom-image-text-section');
    $(section).addClass('hidden-on-load');

    new Waypoint({
      element: blobElement,
      handler: function(direction) {
        if (direction == 'down' && !animated) {

          $(section).removeClass('hidden-on-load');
          reapplyAnimation(blobElement, 'animated-fade-rotate');

          var relatedImage = $(blobElement).closest('.custom-image-text-section').find('.image-container img')[0];
          $(relatedImage).removeClass('hidden-on-load');
          reapplyAnimation(relatedImage, 'animated-slide-rotate');

          var textContainer = $(blobElement).closest('.custom-image-text-section').find('#text-container')[0];
          $(textContainer).removeClass('hidden-on-load');
          reapplyAnimation(textContainer, 'animated-fade-in-slide-in-right');

          animated = true;
          this.destroy();
        }
      },
      offset: '45%' // Trigger point
    });
  });
});

This is the js code I am now using, 4 sections should be revealed as you scroll but only the first is at the moment.
